# Cómo cambia de color de borde del input cuando se detecte por lo menos un caracter y cuando este vacio

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

mi problema es:  ¿Cómo cambiar de color la caja de texto cuando este vacía y cuando se detecte por lo menos un carácter dentro que se cambio a otro color? No se si alguien de ustedes lo ha hecho?. Gracias por su atención.

NOTA: Esto no quiero que funcione con un click o mover el mouse.
Quiero leer cada carácter que entra en la caja: Ejemplo en mi caja de texto tengo un caracter -> T    y lo borro hay es donde mi caja de texto se tiene que poner el color del borde.

Lo que quiero lograr:

Cuando mi caja de texto detecte por lo menos un carácter:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando mi caja de texto detecte que esta vacio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que he investigado: aquí detecta el carácter OK comprendo se activa el color de fondo en mi caso el borde pero cómo, cuando el usuario elimine el ultimo carácter cambie a rojo??.

```
<script>
document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("keypress", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hola Diegos En tu función `myFunction()` no cambies a rojo direactamente y comprueba la longitud del contenido. si es 0, rojo. Si es mayor que 0, verde. Si quieres cambiar el borde no uses `backgroundColor`. Busca qué elementos del input manejan el color del borde. Intentalo y si no te funciona explicanos por qué siguiendo [ask] y  [mcve]. Un saludo  (**por favor, no responder a la pregunta hasta que el autor lo intente y muestre su fallo concreto**)

Comment: Amigo entiendo pero cómo voy a obtener la longitud de caracteres de la caja cuando el usuario elimine ya que el evento keypress se activa cuando recibe un caracter??  Necesito un evento que detecte cuando haya un cambio de caracteres en la caja en todo el tiempo. ó que me recomiendas?

Comment: Ya te lo he recomendado. Tu funcion se activa cuando pulsas una tecla. si pulsas la tecla de borrar, cuentas si hay caracteres o no y cambias el color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dentro de la función comprueba si el contenido está vacío. En tal caso pon el campo en rojo y si no en verde.

Además utiliza "keyup" en lugar de "keypress", ya que de esta forma evaluarás el contenido del campo una vez actualizado.

```js
document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("keyup", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  var campo = document.getElementById("demo");
    if (campo.value == '') {
     campo.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
    else {
      campo.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
}
```

```html
<input id="demo" />
```

Comment: Julio por favor no le respondas dando la solucion ya que asi no ayudas a nadie. Espera a que el autor explique su intento y fallo. Sobre ese fallo podemos ayudarle pero si no se pelea con el problema primero, la pregunta es demasiado amplia. Un saludo

Comment: Con todo respeto, se que debo intentar solucionarlo por mi propia cuenta pero no sea tan estricto de antemano le doy las gracias por responder a todos. Gracias Amigo @Juio Cómo no pensé en evaluar el valor jejeje gracias.  Recordemos que ya es el problema del usuario que copia y pega sin entender nada. Así es la vida. No piense mal pero yo me he estado esforzando en mis investigaciones créame. Hasta luego :).

Comment: @lois6b Lo siento, cuando empecé a redactar la respuesta aun no habías redactado el comentario

Comment: Julio si, no habia hecho el comentario pero segun [answer], no todas las preguntas se deben responder. Y si puse el comentario es porque vi, por experiencia, que esta es una pregunta de baja calidad que recibe respuesta de inmediato al ser sencillo. @DiegosSánchez podria haberlo hecho él solo si lo hubiera intentado antes de preguntar. Un saludo

Comment: Y no hace falta poner enlaces de Jsfiddle ya que tenemos snippets de codigo disponibles pulsando en `<>` en el editor. Te lo edité yo para que veas como funciona. Buena anotacion la de `keyup` pero el autor pide el borde, no el fondo. saludo

Comment: @lois6b, gracias por el edit. Entiendo lo que dices, pero a veces la línea entre lo aceptable y lo que no es delgada. Tampoco podemos presuponer que alguien no intente algo por el hecho de ser sencillo. A mi que dijera que intentaba ver "cuando se eliminaba el último caracter" me daba a entender que había hecho intentos pero que lo estaba enfocando mal. A veces la solución es fácil, estás intentándolo un buen rato y simplemente no la ves. Sí que es cierto que podría haber sido un mejor ejercicio comentar lo de mirar si era blanco pero dejarle para el lo del cambio de evento a `keyup`. Saludos.

Comment: Por supuesto no presupongo. Pero si en la pregunta no tiene explicado eso que ha intentado y que problemas exactgos ha tenido, asumo que no lo ha intentado. Lo que pretendo es que o bien añada lo intentado para mejorar la pregunta o como dices , que esté un rato intnetadolo antes de preguntar. Un saludo